# Google API map loading but not rendering

Tags: javascript, html, api, google-maps

I'm new to js/HTML and am trying to use a project involving the google maps API but am struggling to load the map. It shows the area where the map should be in the cream color but the map itself isn't rendering. The form is working as it should do at this point. I was hoping someone could help or just give me tips on how to improve. Below is my code. The Google maps portion is from lines 22-35.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>My Google Map</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <label>X Co-Ordinate</label>
            <input type="number" id="xcoordinate" placeholder="X Co-Ordinate" />
            <br />
            <label>Y Co-Ordinate</label>
            <input type="number" id="ycoordinate" placeholder="Y Co-Ordinate" />
            <br />
            <label>Message</label>
            <input type="text" id="message" placeholder="Your Message Here" />
            <br />
            <button>SUBMIT</button>
        </form>
        <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 450px;"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDUcYMhqZEf3LBHX1ZuiUrrcThuq6HHms0&callback=createMap&libraries=&v=weekly"
></script>
        <script>
            function createMap() 
            {
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), 
                {
                    zoom: 8,
                    center: { lat: 51.9904, lng: -1.0439 },
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                });
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have a typo: `centre` should be `center` in the [mapOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#MapOptions.center) per the docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how your JS should look like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function createMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      zoom: 8,
      center: { lat: 51.9904, lng: -1.0439 },
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  }
</script>
<script
  type="text/javascript"
  async
  defer
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDUcYMhqZEf3LBHX1ZuiUrrcThuq6HHms0&callback=createMap&libraries=&v=weekly"
></script>
```

You had two things wrong. A typo in 'center' and the Google api url.